# Linking to a css file on a remote machine

Tags: html, css, amazon-ec2

I am working on a remote instance using amazon ec2 instances and created an index.html file. In that HTML file, I have created links to an external CSS file which is in the same directory as my index.html file but when I try it out in chrome it doesn't seem to find the CSS file and gives me a 404 not found an error. I have tried doing the same thing on my local machine and it works just fine there. Am I missing something? How can I fix this issue? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

This is the part of the code i am confused with:

```html
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="signin.css">
</head>
```

Comment: is the file actually uploaded? double check the name.  the permissions.

Comment: yes both the index.html and the css files are on my remote machine. How can i check the permissions? If you mean chmod , then yes.

Comment: if you are using linux `ls -la`.  please search for other questions about permissions, and uploading sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the usual suspects:
1. Renaming your css file
2. Check if it works on you local machine. You've done that, so it's a server related issue.
3. Try absolute path for the css
4. Try other browsers, maybe it's just chrome

Comment: Thank you so much, absolute path did work! But i don't understand why linking to an external file doesn't work.

Comment: Your server might not allow it. Try on another server and if it works you could contact the hosting company and ask for more information on the matter.